# close the dialog box again not opening

Tags: php, yii

Here I have multiple ajax links. On clicking on links the `juidialogbox` is opening. For first time it is working fine. But I have defined an ajax back button in which I have to go back and again come to this page. After second time `renderPartial` the pop up is not coming. Please, help me to resolve this issue.

```
<td><?php echo CHtml::ajaxLink(
    $value['Name'], 
    array('mis/getBeneficiarydetails', 'idno' => $value['IDNO']), 
    array( 'beforeSend' => 'function(){
          $("#update_selector").addClass("loading");
      }', 
      'success' => 'function(r){
          $("#juiDialogbox").html(r).dialog("open"); 
          return false;
      }', 
      'complete' => 'function(){
          $("#update_selector").removeClass("loading");
      }', array('id' => 'showjuiDialogbox' . $i, 'live' => false), )); 
</td>
```

Comment: So what is your question? You'll have to be more descriptive than this. What are your trying to do? What are the expected results? What is not working as it should?

Comment: For Multiple ajax reuest cjuidialog box pop up not working.in second time renderPartial to a page it loads the page twice so that i think thats the problm.how to fix the issue?Please..........

Comment: Here i have defined the ajax links:  <td><?php
            echo CHtml::ajaxLink($value['Name'], array('mis/getBeneficiarydetails', 'idno' => $value['IDNO']), array(
                'beforeSend' => 'function(){$("#update_selector").addClass("loading");}',
                'success' => 'function(r){$("#juiDialogbox").html(r).dialog("open"); return false;}',
                'complete' => 'function(){$("#update_selector").removeClass("loading");}',
                array('id' => 'showjuiDialogbox' . $i, 'live' => false),
            ));
           </td>

Comment: You should also update the question with some code - the parts you believe are responsible for the problem you're trying to solve.. And, I see that you're mentioning `here I have` multiple times, but there are no links to what you're referring to. Should there be any links or are you just struggling with English? To add the link to the question, you should select the text where you want to put the link, and then click on the icon that looks like a globe with a little green arrow. A popup should occur where you should enter desired link..

Comment: I've updated your question with the code you provided. Maybe you could also add the differences between outputted HTML when you're coming to this page first time and the outputted HTML when you're returning with the back button.

Comment: The page before back button and after back button is coming correct.But the issue i have found after clicking on the back button the page is not remove from the cache.And when next time i am clicking on the ajax link the pop up page loaded two times .i.e one from the cache and another from the second time renderPartial.

Comment: can u give me ur email id so that i can send u my code files?

Comment: If it's loading 2 times, it seems to me that it's probably javascript related - you've probably attached 2 event handlers to your AJAX link - first handler was attached the first time you came to the page, and the second time after you went back using AJAX. To confirm that, try debugging your `success` to see if it's been called more than once..

Comment: yes if i am giving alert under success then first time it is coming once .bUt second time after back the alert is coming twice.So what should i write under success to load the page only once before and after back button click?

Comment: I've added the answer based on your input..